# Optimizing flood-fill alike algorithm (percolation theory)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here my python code :

```
from numpy import *
from copy import *

def Grid(s, p):
    return random.binomial(1, p, (s,s))

def InitialSpill(G, i, j):
    G[i, j] = 2

def Fillable(G, i, j):
    if i > 0 and G[i - 1, j] == 2:
            return True
    if j > 0 and G[i, j - 1] == 2:
            return True
    if i < len(G) - 1 and G[i + 1, j] == 2:
            return True
    if j < len(G) - 1 and G[i, j + 1] == 2:
            return True
    return False

def Fill(G):
    F = copy(G)
    for i in range(len(G)):
        for j in range(len(G)):
            if F[i, j] == 2:
                G[i, j] = 3 # 3 denote a "dry" cell
            elif F[i, j] == 1 and Fillable(F, i, j):
                G[i, j] = 2 # 2 denote a "filled" cell

def EndReached(G): # Check if all filled cells are dry and if no cells are fillable
    for i in range(len(G)):
        for j in range(len(G)):
            if (G[i, j] == 1 and Fillable(G, i, j)) or G[i, j] == 2:
                    return False
    return True

def Prop(G): # yield the ratio between dry and total fillable cells
    (dry, unrch) = (0, 0)
    for e in G:
        for r in e:
            if r == 1:
                unrch += 1
            if r == 3:
                dry += 1
    if unrch == 0 and dry < 2:
        return 0
    return dry / (unrch + dry)

def Percolate(s, p, i, j): #Percolate a generated matrix of size n, probability p
    G = Grid(s, p)
    InitialSpill(G, i, j)
    while not EndReached(G):
        Fill(G)
    return Prop(G)

def PercList(s, i, j, n, l):
    list_p = linspace(0, 1, n)
    list_perc = []
    for p in list_p:
        sum = 0
        for i in range(l):
            sum += Percolate(s, p, i, j)
        list_perc += [sum/l]
    return (list_p, list_perc)
```

The idea is to represent a percolatable field with a matrix, where :

- 0 is a full, unfillable cell
- 1 is an empty, fillable cell
- 2 is a filled cell (will become dry => 3)
- 3 is a dry cell (already filled, hence unfillable)

I want to represent the ratio of dry/total fillable cells as a function of p (the probability that a cell is full in the matrix).

However, my code is extremely unefficient (take a lot of time to complete, even with smalls values).

How can I optimize it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is not very efficient because while you use numpy, most of the calculations are done element wise (double loops over 2D array elements, etc.) which is slow in Python.

There are two possible approaches, to speed this up,

1. You vectorize your code so it uses optimized numpy operators for arrays. For instance, instead of having a function `Fillable(G, i, j)` that returns a boolean, you define a function `Fillable(G)` that returns a boolean numpy array for all the `i`, `j` indices at a time (without using loops),

   ```
   def Fillable(G):
        res = np.zeros(G.shape, dtype='bool')
        # if i > 0 and G[i - 1, j] == 2:
        # find indices where this is true
        imask, jmask = np.where(G == 2)
        imask, jmask = imask.copy(), jmask.copy() # make them writable
        imask -= 1   # shift i indices
        imask, jmask = imask[imask>=0], jmask[jmask>=0]
        res[imask, jmask] = True
        # [..] do the other conditions in a similar way
        return res
   ```

   This then allows us to remove the double loop from the `Fill(G)` function, for instance with,

   ```
   def Fill(G):
       G[G==2] = 3
       G[(G==1) & Fillable(G)] = 2
   ```

   Pretty much most of this code could be rewritten in a similar fashion.
2. Another alternative is to use [Cython](http://cython.org/). In this case the code structure could be kept unmodified, and simply adding types would significantly speed things up. For instance, an optimized function `Fill` for Cython would be,

   ```
   cpdef int Fill(int [:,::1] G):
       cdef int [:,::1] F = G.base.copy()
       cdef int i, j, N
       N = G.base.shape[0]
       for i in range(N):
           for j in range(N):
               if F[i, j] == 2:
                   G[i, j] = 3 
               elif F[i, j] == 1 and Fillable(F, i, j):
                   G[i, j] = 2 
       return 0
   ```

In any case, you should first [profile your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/582337/1791279), to see which function calls take the most time. It's possible that just optimizing one or two critical function would speed this up by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Would using `numpy.vectorize` with `Fillable` a good idea ? I was wondering if there couldn't also be  a branch prediction thing as the  array is generated randomly (and `Fillable` is somehow full of conditionals statements)

Comment: Well, according to the documentation  "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.", so it probably won't be faster.  If you use Cython, the C compiler will do it's best to do branch prediction: it's not something you can control in Python though, but anyway, that's rather fine tuning. Simply using numpy or Cython for loops will bring a major performance improvement.

Comment: But how can I define a `Fillable` function that doesn't use loops as I need to work on cells indexes ? (e.g. $i-1, j$). By the way, is there any tool that could help me with painlessly "profiling" my code ?

Comment: I updated the answer above to illustrate vectorization of the `Fillable` function and added a link regarding profiling.

Comment: After profiling, I tried to vectorize the `Prop` function. Is `(dry, unrch) = ((G == 3).sum(), (G == 1).sum())` more vectorized ?

Comment: @servabat  Yes,  that is much better. The numpy's sum operator also uses a loop over items, but it is implemented in C not Python, which makes it much more efficient.

Comment: I find it quite surprising that the result are like 10x better (on profiling at least), while I guess there is still a loop, just hidden by a function :o Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually, isn't the `F=G.copy()` in `Fill` unnecessary with that vectorized approach ?